# django-imagekit - better way of showing a default image?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-imagekit

I'm using [django-imagekit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit) to resize my user avatars and right now to display a default avatar (if the user didn't upload his/her avatar) I do this:

**views.py**

```
    try:
        usr_avatar = UsrAvatar.objects.get(user=request.user.id)        
    except UsrAvatar.DoesNotExist: 
        usr_avatar = UsrAvatar.objects.get(id='0')
```

**template.html**

```
<img src="{{ usr_avatar.avatar_image.url }}" >
```

This works fine but every time a user didn't upload his/her avatar I'm hitting the database for the default avatar image.

Is there a way to eliminate hitting the database when the user doesn't have an avatar image loaded by somehow attributing the default image link to `usr_avatar` or just doing something in the template.html? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apt username given your question!

You could create a [context processor](http://blog.madpython.com/2010/04/07/django-context-processors-best-practice/) that provides the default avatar to every template and simply make sure that the context processor caches the image

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'myapp.context_processors.default_avatar',
...
)
```

**myapp/context_processors.py**

```
from django.core.cache import cache 
def default_avatar(request):
    default_avatar = cache.get('default_avatar', False)
    if not default_avatar:
        default_avatar = UsrAvatar.object.get(id='0')
    return {
        'default_avatar' : default_avatar
    }
```

Now the template variable 'default_avatar' is available in every template:

```
{% if usr_avatar %}
    {{ usr_avatar }}
{% else %}
    {{ default_avatar }}
{% endif %}
```

*Alternatively* just use the cache in your original query:

```
try:
    usr_avatar = UsrAvatar.objects.get(user=request.user.id)        
except UsrAvatar.DoesNotExist: 
    usr_avatar = cache.get('default_avatar', False)
    if not usr_avatar:
        usr_avatar = UsrAvatar.objects.get(id='0')
```

**But Finally**, it might be even better to avoid keeping the default avatar in the database at all and instead just write a context processor like above but instead of getting the default avatar from the DB, just have a static url to the image

```
from django.conf import settings
def default_avatar(request):
    return {
        'default_avatar' : '%simages/default_avatar.jpg' % settings.STATIC_URL
    }
```

Comment: @pastylegs How would the static link solution would look like? Thank you!

Comment: Well, any static media is being served by your web server so all you are really doing is providing the path to the image you are going to use as the default avatar so in the context processor simply return a path on the server to your default image avatar